# "TooManyTopics" Dispatch Error and Contract Revert when Minting in OpenBrush PSP37 Smart Contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts, substrate-node, openbrush

I am facing an issue with the `OpenBrush PSP37` smart contract while calling the `mint` function. I receive a `Contract Reverted!` error with a `TooManyTopics` dispatch error. However, upon inspecting the substrate blockchain code, it specifies that up to 4 topics are allowed. In my case, I am only using 4 topics, as visible in the attached screenshot. Could someone please help me understand why I am encountering the "TooManyTopics" error? Surprisingly, when I reduce the number of topics to 3, the contract works fine.

I have previously addressed this issue, and it was recommended that we adhere to a maximum limit of four topics. However, even when we precisely utilize four topics, we continue to encounter the same error. You can find our previous discussion at this Stack Overflow post :[enter link description here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9167/getting-contract-reverted-error-with-toomanytopics-dispatch-error-when-call/9169#9169)

Could anyone shed some light on this issue? Is there a possible explanation for receiving the `TooManyTopics` error even when using the maximum allowed number of topics?

Thank you for your valuable insights and suggestions.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c37WC.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#[ink(topic)]` is use to index the events, you can find more info about it [here](https://use.ink/basics/events#event-definition), now to answer your question that you are unable to use 4 `ink(topics)` at a time is that one of the `ink(topic)` is used by the signature of the event as mentioned in above link, if you want to use all the 4 topics for you event than use `#[ink(anonymous)]` it will not include the signature of event as an `ink(topic)` and you are good to go. You can use #[ink(anonymous)] as follows:

```
#[ink(event)]
#[ink(anonymous)]
pub struct MyEvent {
    #[ink(topic)]
    field_1: i32,
    field_2: bool,
}
```